# How to pull info of a protocol's data using useContractRead hook of wagmi?

Tags: ethers.js, wagmi

I need to get data on all transactions on an L2 protocol. I'm using the useContractRead hook.

```
const contractRead = useContractRead({
    address:  address,
    abi: ContractABI,
    functionName: 'functionName'
})
console.log(contractRead);
```

console.log(contractRead);

The data returned is undefined.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way for reusability is to first set up a json file with address and abi and a config for the contract:

```typescript
import config from '../path/to/contractConfig.json'

const contractConfig = {
  address: config.address,
  abi: config.abi
};
```

Now you don't have to re-write the address and abi in every single function call you're making.

Then you need to identify what type of data you're receiving from the `useContractRead()` hook, as per the wagmi documentation:

```typescript
const { data: functionData } = useContractRead({
  ...contractConfig,
  functionName: 'functionName',
});
```

Then you can take that data and use elsewhere, passing the `functionData` variable in as needed.

However, by default, the `useContractRead()` can lead to attempting to fetch the data every block, which can lead to rate-limiting if you're running directly through RPC providers, so it's a good idea to write a custom hook to handle that data before you pass it to your app.

*Here's an example of wrapping two reads together with a check to ensure the contract doesn't try to read every single block. You can do the same with just one instance of `useContractRead`:*

```typescript
const handleContractReads = () => {
  const { data: dataOne } = useContractRead({
    ...contractConfig,
    functionName: 'functionOne',
    watch: true,
    onError: (err) => { console.error(err) }
  });
  const { data: dataTwo } = useContractRead({
    ...contractConfig,
    functionName: 'functionTwo',
    watch: true,
    onError: (err) => { console.error(err) }
  });
  // Perform a check before fetching contract data.
  if (!someCondition) return null;
  SetVarOne(dataOne);
  setVarTwo(dataTwo);
}
```